# Why StringBuilder append() faster than LinkedList add()?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, linked-list, stringbuilder

I'm trying to create new StringBuilder based on LinkedList structure.

As you know Java's StringBuilder append() operation works like array list add() operation(resizing value-array when capacity exceeds).

I realised that when inserting `String`, `StringBuilder.append()` faster than `LinkedList.add()`

(*It's a pure adding process for list).

Here is the code snippet:

```
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        int loopCount = 5_000_000;

        long s, e;

        s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            linkedList.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\n");
        }
        e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("LinkedList: "+(e - s));

        s = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            stringBuilder.append(UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "\n");
        }
        e = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("String Builder: " + (e - s));
```

Those are the benchmark results.(Based on 5 million insertion)

```
StringBuilder: 13892 millisec
LinkedList:    19561 millisec
```

Also I changed add() method with `ListIterator.add()` but I did not change anything.

Here is my question: How can I achieve that list add() method become way faster than `StringBuilder.append()`?

Comment: You should use microbenchmarking for this kind of tests. Also, you're comparing apples to pears... A StringBuilder is not a list and LinkedList is not a string builder. So I don't see the point of what you're trying to do...

Comment: *"As you know Java's StringBuilder class works like array list."* No, I don't know that. In fact, I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Have you tried with an `ArrayList`? Excepted when the backing array capacity has to be increased (which should not be too frequent), inserting in an `ArrayList`should be faster than in a `LinkedList`.

Comment: Your benchmark could be giving unreliable results because the JIT compiler may choose to optimize away dead code. See also [avoiding benchmarking pitfalls in the JVM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html).

Comment: I know it's not list implementation , i'm trying to create new StringBuilder like String concat Data Structure based on LinkedList algorithm.Java's StringBuilder works like ArrayList.So i thought new StringBuilder can work like LinkedList and concat all strings within list.So there might be faster than Java's StringBuilder.

Comment: Your starting point is incorrect. `StringBuilder` is backed by a `char[]` http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when saying "works like array list" , i mean if capacity exceeds new array will be created and old data copies on new one and goes like that(resizing every capacity exceeds).

Comment: @neat159: Right. And that's not remotely true of `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 1):

When you add item to  `LinkedList` new `Node` object is created

```
void linkLast(E e) {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(l, e, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (l == null)
            first = newNode;
        else
            l.next = newNode;
        size++;
        modCount++;
    }
```

The `Node` object contains a references to next and previous Nodes.

`StringBuilder` appends String chars to underlying array by native `System.arraycopy` , so no any instances are created.

That could affect on time when multiple these Node instances are created.